# How to pass custom elements list to the class attribute properly?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have the line in my template:

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3 {{ foo_classes }}">
```

If the `foo_classes` is empty I get `class="class1 class2 class3 "`.
What I want to get is `class="class1 class2 class3"` with no additional space at the end of the classes list.

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3{{ foo_classes }}">
```

If I delete the space (look at the line above) then I get `class="class1 class2 class3class4 class5"`, which is no better.

How do I pass additional classes to avoid getting unnecessary space at the end of the classes section if the `foo_classes` is empty?

Comment: there is any special reason about this extra space at the end of `class` attribute of tag to became a problem? just curious about.

Comment: The browser will treat `class="class1 class2 class3 "` and `class="class1 class2 class3"` the same way, so one option is to not worry about the space.

Comment: There is no special reason, I am just curious is avoiding the space really worth adding additional `{% if %}` statement to template.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use the [`if`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if) tag:

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3{% if foo_classes %} {{ foo_classes }}{% endif %}">
```

Comment: I see, but I would also want not to add an additional template tags/logic stuff in templates. Is this the best/only way to do this? Also, is leaving the space at the end of classes list really a problem or could I leave it be?

Comment: @Dibidalidomba Whitespace at the end of the classes list is not _really_ a problem. It happens a lot, especially in situations like this. It's more overhead to have the `{% if %}` statement than any extra size the whitespace might add.

Answer (score 1):

If it's so much of a problem, change the way You add classes to the template so You always use only the variable:

`<div class="{{ foo_classes }}">`

So You will always store `class1 class2 class3` inside that variable, but sometimes You will toggle it with additional/extra class (`class1 class2 class3 class4` for example)

It's pretty common solution, e.g. in Vue.js world, where You tend to store dynamic list of classes inside a variable and pass it into template instead concatenating strings.